# Issue with Oracle Stored Function

Tags: sql, plsql, oracle11g

I am trying to build a stored function in Oracle PL/SQL that will return the most recent rental date for a given registration.

My function is as follows:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE Function rec_date_sf(reg_in IN varchar2)
RETURN DATE
IS
  lv_max_date DATE;
Begin
  SELECT MAX(Date_Rent_Start)
    INTO lv_max_date
    FROM i_booking
   WHERE reg_in = registration;
   RETURN lv_max_date;
END;
```

I am required to call the function in an SQL statement so I am using a registration I know is in the table:

```
SELECT rec_date_sf(date_rent_start), 
       registration
  FROM i_booking 
 WHERE registration = 'E246WFC';
```

This is returning a blank for the `rec_date_sf` function rather than producing the max date.

Could someone please cast their eye over this code and tell me where I am going wrong?

Comment: Just a suggestion - never mix SQL a PL/SQL like that. You can get into very surprising problem. Only only with performance, but also the query can return wrong results. Or at least use `serializable isolation level`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like it's a bit mixed up: you are passing what looks like a date to a function that is taking in a character parameter.

Maybe you want something like this?

```
SELECT rec_date_sf(registration) as date_rent_start, 
       registration
  FROM i_booking 
 WHERE registration = 'E246WFC';
```